# Show that the vectors $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent...

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the vectors $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2
\end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
3
\end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent, and find the unique coefficients $x$ with
\begin{equation*}
x_1v_1+x_2v_2 = [v_1, v_2]x = \begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
To show that the vectors are independent we just row reduce the matrix containing the two vectors to make sure we get the identity matrix right.
My question is how do we find the unique constants with that equation shown?
Thank you.

Comment: How about solve $A^{-1} \cdot (a,b)^t$ where $A$ is the matrix consisting of the two column vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If you look at the first coordinate, you'll see that $1x_1 + 2x_2 = a$, and if you look at the second you will see that $2x_1 + 3x_2 = b$. Do you know how to solve systems of linear equations?

Comment: Yup $x_1 = 2b-3a$ and $x_2 = 2a-b$.

Comment: @squenshl Well done.

Answer (score 2):

The determinant of the following matrix is not zero:

\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
2 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}

Hence the volume created by these two vectors is not zero in 2D. Therefore, they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is just to note that two vectors are linearly independent as long as they're not multiples of each other.

The hint by @Integrate This leads to $\begin {pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3&2\\2&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$, after inverting the $2×2$ matrix.